# Uploading files from a remote location and removing does not work in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, carrierwave

i have a nested ressource Picture for a User model. if i try to upload a picture with a "remote_file_url" it uploads the pictures in the carrierwave tmp directory but did not moves them to the actual dir. that "should" be a validation problem. but it is not. it does work in the console just fine:

```
p = Picture.find(360)
p.remote_file_url = "http://example.com/somepic.jpg"
p.save!
```

my Parameters for the request for updating the user with picture:

```
 "user"=>{"pictures_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"remote_file_url"=>"http://example.com/somepic.jpg", "id"=>"359"}
```

if i upload without the remote_file_url (just the input file field), it works:

```
 "user"=>{"pictures_attributes"=>{"0"=> { "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http>, "remote_file_url"=>"",  "id"=>"359"}
```

the same problem occurs when i use the "remove_file" feature. works just fine in the console, but does not work with the view/controller update.

===================

**Update**

controller:

```
  def update
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes!(params[:user])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :json => @user.to_json(:methods => [:pictures]) }
        format.html {redirect_to :back, :notice  => "Successfully updated user."}
      end
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Picture Model:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :file, :file_cache, :remove_file, :position, :remote_file_url
  mount_uploader :file, PictureUploader
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User Model

```
# encoding: UTF-8
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :remote_file_url, :beta_token, :wants_gender, :gender, :radius, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :region, :latitude, :longitude, :gmaps, :pictures_attributes
  has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

pretty basic stuff.... i removed the devise definitions for the user model....

```
= simple_form_for @user, :url => profile_path(@user) do |f|
  %ul.profiles.users
    - @user.pictures.each_with_index do |picture, i|
      %li.user
      .fields
        = f.simple_fields_for :pictures, picture do |picture_from|
          - if picture.file.present?
            = picture_from.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean
          = picture_from.input :position
          = picture_from.input :file
          = picture_from.input :remote_file_url, :as => :hidden
          = picture_from.input :file_cache
```

Comment: Whats the view look like? and whats the code for the controller?

Comment: Whats the actual erb for the view?

Comment: i just noticed that the "remove_file" does not work either. i use rails 3.1 with ruby 1.9.2 if that helps...

Answer (score 2):

It's because of attr_accessible. If you make the mounted uploader's instance variable name attr_accessible, Ruby is going to create accessors for you... which will interfere with CarrierWave's setter.

Don't make any mounted uploader variable names attr_accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in that when I set the remote_image_url the image doesn't save along with the model itself.

The problem was that the picture was not saving after the remote_image_url was set.

This was cause because I called a delegated method `self.taker = 'Andrew'` from User model, which automatically saves 'Andrew' in the picture.taker onto the database. I had to avoid that and use 'self.picture.taker = 'Andrew' to avoid the picture from being persisted. Then when I call user.save it will save the associated picture and have thumbnail images created correctly.

This case is specific, but the point is that check if your picture object has actually been saved after the remote_image_url has been set.